# Have migrations and a service that needs the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I build a service that needs access to my database while also using migrations, given that the migrations tool `"dotnet ef database update"` runs my application `BuildWebHost` before creating the database? The attempt to configure the service needing the database throws an exception because the database doesn't exist and causes the migration command to fail. The database therefore never gets created.

I'm using asp.net core 2 and EF Core 2.

More specifically, running `"dotnet ef database update"` with a blank database fails with the following error:

> An error occurred while calling method 'BuildWebHost' on class
>   'Program'.Continuing without the application service provider. Error:
>   Cannot open database "MyDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'MYCOMPUTER\MYNAME'.

This happens because I have built a custom configuration provider backed by my "MyDb" database (with the end goal of binding to it with a custom options class) as per this [Microsoft Configuration Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#create-an-entity-framework-custom-provider) My program.cs looks like:

```
 public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                {
                    var tmpconfig = config.Build();
                    config.AddMyOptionsConfig(options => options.UseSqlServer(tmpconfig.GetConnectionString("My_Database")));
                })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
```

and the AddMyOptionsConfig eventually runs:

```
  public class EFConfigProvider : ConfigurationProvider
    {
     [...]

        // Load config data from EF DB.
        public override void Load()
        {
            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            OptionsAction(builder);

            using (var dbContext = new MyDbContext(builder.Options))
            {    
                 // dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated(); // will cause first migration to fail
                 Data = !dbContext.ConfigurationValue.Any() // throws exception
                      ? CreateAndSaveDefaultValues(dbContext)
                      : dbContext.ConfigurationValue.ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c => c.Value);
```

which throws an `SQLException` when it attempts to access the database because the database hasn't been created yet.

However, if I try to use `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` then the initial migration fails because the tables already exist. I thought of trying `dbContext.Database.Migrate()` instead but as a beginner I'm concerned there might be unintended consequences for a production environment. As such I'd prefer to have control over migrations via the command line tools.

Fundamentally, the problem seems to be that `"dotnet ef database update"` runs the application startup - `BuildWebHost` - before it creates the database but the custom configuration provider added in `BuildWebHost` needs the database to already exist.

How do I solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sense, you've created a circular reference. When running migrations on a ASP.NET Core project, the application is initialized to instantiate the `DbContext` needed to run migrations against. This is due to the fact that `DbContext` in EF Core now requires a `DbContextOptions` instance to be injected, as opposed to the old way of doing things in EF, where the connection string name (or the actual full connection string) would be defined directly on the constructor.

Normally, this would work just fine, but, as you've noticed, because the application initialization, itself, requires an already existing database, there's no way to run this before the migrations. As a result, you have two options:

1. You can attempt to abstract the piece that requires an existing database. That could be as simple as wrapping it in a try-catch and swallowing the exception, or more complex. Since the migration piece doesn't need this particular functionality, it could safely be excluded from the application initialization in that scenario.
2. You can move your context and entities into a class library and implement an [`IDesignTimeDbContextFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-idesigntimedbcontextfactorytcontext) to satisfy the ability to construct a `DbContext` to migrate against. You would then run the migrations against this class library instead of your ASP.NET Core project. That then sidesteps the issue of having to initialize the application in order to do a migration.

Comment: 1 works but does leave the code - when running normally - potentially swallowing exceptions that should be propagated.

Comment: That would be where the something "more complex" would come in. I haven't tried this myself, but it's possible you could feed off something like HttpContext, which will probably be very different in a "running migrations" scenario vs. actually responding to a request. The point is to just find some way to not enforce that code being run as part of the migration process.

Comment: I realized from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dbcontext-creation) that I could achieve the same effect as 2 but without needing a separate project by renaming BuildWebHost. The IDesignTimeDbContextFactory looks like the best general solution. It did open up another can of worms for me in that my database connection string is in user secrets, and configuration for that requires IHostingEnvironment, which isn't available outside of BuildWebHost. I'm sure there will be an alternative way of configuring it though.

Answer (score 0):

`BuildWebHost` (and `Startup.Configure`) shouldn't be used for application startup logic. The guidance from the ASP.NET team is to use `Program.Main` instead.

Comment: I'm trying to add a custom options class as a service. How do I add a service outside of `BuildWebHost` (and `Startup.ConfigureServices`)? I can't see any way to do this.

Comment: Can you add the service but make it lazy so it doesn't run the code that's failing at design time?

Comment: It's a built-in dotnet core service `services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);` but I had a quick look to see. My suspicion is that the database is hit as soon as `IConfigurationBuilder.Build()` is called, which I assume happens before Startup. I love the way the tooling detects the dbContexts but I guess there's always the exceptional case. 

(For my reference, the advice on application startup logic you refer to looks like it's [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/#move-database-initialization-code).)

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to use `reloadOnChange` with the custom `ConfigurationProvider` so that the service can initialise backed by fake data, have a change event triggered before the first real use, then connect to the database on reload.

Answer (score 0):

My solution so far has been to move the entity backing the custom configuration provider into a separate dbContext.

Now the table can be created when needed via `MyDbOptionsContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` without affecting the migrations, as they are based on the main context (`MyDbContext`).

The options table no longer participates in migrations but as it's unlikely to change there shouldn't be a problem. The other downside is the need (due to having 2 contexts) to explicitly specify the context for the `dotnet ef` command line tool.